# Loading Satellite Imagery Into Trimble GeoExplorer

Tags: geotiff-tiff, trimble

How would I go about loading satellite imagery in TIFF format as a background file or image into my Trimble GeoExplorer?

Comment: It is up to the software you run on your GeoExplorer. Is is TerraSync, ArcPad or something else? Select the manual to read accordingly.

Comment: It is TerraSync

Comment: Do you have a manual? I have lost mine but I have used images in TerraSync and I know it is possible. I probably used jpeg + world files which is actually a bad option but OK for small images. I would recommend to use some tiled GeoTIFF variant but you must find out what kind of tiffs are supported.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most straigh-forward method is to use Pathfinder Office.  Load the images into Pathfinder Office as backgrounds, be sure to provide projection information.  Once they are in Pathfinder Office you can use the Data Transfer Utility to send them to the device.  TIFFs are supported in TerraSync, but I have had issues with some of them not wanting to draw.  Keep in mind that there is very little onboard storage on most GeoExplorers, so the smaller the files the better.

You can also just move the file directly to your device using Windows Explorer.  Copy it over to the MyDocuments/TerraSync folder on the Geo (the same folder where your data dictionary is stored).  Before loading it in as a background, you will need to be sure that the correct coordinate system is set in Terra Sync. Once you have done that, just load it in as a background and TerraSync will display it.

To use it as a background in Terra Sync go to Map > Layers > Background and select the TIFF.

You might want to indicate the version of Terra Sync and Pathfinder Office and model of the GeoExplorer you are using for future questions.

Comment: I can attest to the fact that GeoExplorers (even with additional on board storage) do not like displaying aerial imagery rasters - very slow to load as a background file and long refresh times if you have to move your map screen extents. I would suggest clipping your imagery to the smallest extent that serves your purposes before loading.